# Can I get an example of VB.NET (VB2017) web forms using ASP.NET Identity without Entity Framework?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, webforms, asp.net-identity

I am not able to find anything on google for using VB.NET (VB2017) web forms using ASP.NET Identity without Entity Framework.  I have dozens of VB.NET web applications using the old ASP.NET 2.0 standard SQL Server Membership that must be converted to use the newer ASP.NET Identity. There are no VB.NET examples out there...

VB.NET WebForms .NET 4.6.1 framework SQLServer tables matching generated EF tables with minimal columns, ID, Name, Roles

I have a version using Entity Framework working, but I need to use our existing Intranet Users database. This is the code I am stuck on in Login.aspx.vb SignIn

```vb
Dim userStore = New UserStore(Of IdentityUser)()
Dim userManager = New UserManager(Of IdentityUser)(userStore)
```

> Option Strict On disallows implicit conversions from 'UserStore(Of IdentityUser)' to 'IUserStore(Of IdentityUser)'.

I am stuck trying to figure out what I am missing...

My Login.aspx.vb is the start web page for the project. The SignIn method is what I need updated.

```vb
Imports Microsoft.AspNet.Identity
Imports Microsoft.Owin.Security
Imports System
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Web.UI.WebControls
Partial Public Class Login
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        If Not IsPostBack Then
            If User.Identity.IsAuthenticated Then
                StatusText.Text = String.Format("Hello {0}!!", User.Identity.GetUserName())
                LoginStatus.Visible = True
                LogoutButton.Visible = True
            Else
                LoginForm.Visible = True
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
    Protected Sub SignIn(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        Dim userStore = New UserStore(Of IdentityUser)()
        Dim userManager = New UserManager(Of IdentityUser)(userStore)
        Dim user = userManager.Find(UserName.Text, Password.Text)
        If user IsNot Nothing Then
            Dim authenticationManager = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication
            Dim userIdentity = userManager.CreateIdentity(user, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie)
            authenticationManager.SignIn(New AuthenticationProperties() With {.IsPersistent = False}, userIdentity)
            Response.Redirect("~/Login.aspx")
        Else
            StatusText.Text = "Invalid username or password."
            LoginStatus.Visible = True
        End If
    End Sub
    Protected Sub SignOut(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        Dim authenticationManager As IAuthenticationManager = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication
        authenticationManager.SignOut()
        Response.Redirect("~/Login.aspx")
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Did you try following the implied recommendation of the error message and insert the missing conversion operation?  Does `UserStore(Of T)` actually implement `IUserStore(Of T)`?